# Проблема с :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Не работает трансформация при наведении,подскажите что не так?
.menu не расширяется при наведении на него

```css
.menu {
     width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:orange;
  transform:scale(0.5);
}
.menu:hover {
 transform:scale(1);
}
.show-menu {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:black;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1000;
 top:33px;
 left:33px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="show-menu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Потому что вы уменьшили `menu`  и теперь оно прячется за `show-menu` ...  вот если вы уберете `transform:scale(0.5);` вы сразу это увидите.....и да `scale(1)` ничего не делает.... это равносильно умножению на 1...... надо писать хотя бы  `scale(2)` или что-то больше 1

Answer (score 1):

В дополнении к вышенаписанному, menu прячется за show-menu по причине того, что у последнего стоит z-index: 1000 , поэтому даже если в html вы поставите menu выше, оно все равно будет на нижнем слое. Посмотрите на css ниже. И если стоит scale(0,5) получается вы уменьшили на 50%, а при hover поставили scale(1) - возврат к 100%, так что в данном случае scale(1) срабатывает.

```css
.menu {
   width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:orange;
  transform: scale(0.5);
   z-index:1001;
}
.menu:hover {
 transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.show-menu {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:black;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1000;
 top:33px;
 left:33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="show-menu"></div>
```